# Change the icon by changing the API data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, icons

I want to make a web with the subject of weather. I got to the point in the construction process that the icon should change with the change of weather.

```js
    let shiftIcon = () => {

        let icon = "";
        let iconText = data.date[0].weather.code;

        if (iconText == 600) {
            icon = "https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/48/000000/external-wind-weather-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons.png";
            return (
                <img src={icon} />
            );
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

```html
   <div className="col col-3">
     {shiftIcon()}
 </div>
```

And after writing this code, I got an error. Do you have a solution for this?

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') shiftIcon
> E:/Projects and trainings/Education Courses/react.js
> courses/Person/weather-application/src/components/boxNew.js:32   29 |
> let shiftIcon = () => {   30 |    31 |        let icon = ""
>
> > 32 |        let iconText = data.date[0].weather.code;
> > | ^  33 |    34 |        if (iconText == 600) {   35 |            icon =
> > "https://img.icons8.com/external-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons/48/000000/external-wind-weather-those-icons-lineal-color-those-icons.png";

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: As it stands your code works fine. You just need to ensure that `data` exists, and that you can extract information from it. How are you fetching the data? That code is missing from your question.

Comment: There is a free public weather api called **weatherDB**, which is easy and simple to implement You can try it once. Site: https://weatherdbi.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially `data` is undefined. You should use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to get rid of the runtime exceptions.

Try like this

```
let iconText = data?.date?.[0]?.weather?.code;
```